# Preposition "to" in "join (to) a noun"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

> Prepositions are the words that join a noun, pronoun or the noun phrases and make each sentence complete. However, learning preposition is little tricky and hence, students should be conscious while reading a book or other documents and check the usage of the preposition.
>   ([Medium](https://medium.com/@english_grammar/how-to-use-preposition-in-english-grammar-on-at-in-of-for-2fdb11e80029))

Why is the preposition "to" not used in this sentence? Like this:

> Prepositions are the words that join **to** a noun, pronoun or the noun phrases and make each sentence complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the sentence was written by someone whose first language is not English. Use of the verb "join" in that way, reads a little oddly. But "join" used in this way as an intransitive verb does not demand "to". You join a club or society, a couple might be joined in matrimony. As a transitive verb, "to" is appropriate when identifying direct and indirect objects - I joined the wires to the light fitting.

Comment: What word would you put in?

Comment: I think I'd say something like "Prepositions are words used before a noun, pronoun or a noun phrase which explain the relationship between the action described by a verb, and the noun." Oh - and please ignore what I said about an intransitive form. I had a brainstorm! The bit about direct/indirect objects is what you need. :-)

Comment: Hi @Ian, I clarified the context a bit. The blockquoted text was not the original. The bolded "to" was OP's inclusion. Not sure if you were aware. I was fine with making the edit since I didn't think it invalidated your answer. Basically, I think your answer still stands, just the first sentence might need to be updated.

Comment: Hi Em - that's fine. Yes, I did catch that the "to" was inserted. My first sentence stands.